# DD text inline with DT

Tags: html, css, semantic-markup

I'm hoping to be able to use a definition list `<dl>` to format something like this:

[image]

The HTML is something like this:

```html
<dl>
  <dt>Abandonnement</dt>
  <dd>m. an abandonning, quitting, forsaking, leaving off, giving over, laieng open for, prostituting vnto, others; also a proscribing or outlawing.
    <dl>
      <dt>Abandonnément de raison.</dt>
      <dd>a wilfull defection, revolting, or swarming, from reason.</dd>
    </dl>
  </dd>
</dl>
```

However, whatever I do, I can't get the `<dt>` and `<dd>` to look like inline text. The closest I got was to float the `<dt>` left (bolding for emphasis):

```css
dt {
  font-weight: bold;
  float:left;
  clear: left;
  padding-right: 0.5em;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/dL6mkba3/2/

However, as it is, the `line-height` of the `<dt>` prevents a natural wrap to the next line, and adjusting the `margin-bottom` to something negative causes the `<dd>` to be too close when the `<dt>` itself wraps.

Is there an easy way to format this with definition lists, or should I just use, say, a `<ul>` and forget `<dl>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this a feasible answer?

```css
dl {
  padding-left: 1em;
  text-indent: -1em;
}
dt {
  font-weight: bold;
  display: inline;
}
dd {
  display: inline;
  margin-left: 0.5em;
}
.subdef {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-block: 0.2em;
  padding-left: 0;
  text-indent: 0;
}
```

```html
<dl>
  <dt>Abandonnement</dt>
  <dd>m. an abandonning, quitting, forsaking, leaving off, giving over, laieng open for, prostituting vnto, others; also a proscribing or outlawing.
    <dl class="subdef">
      <dt>Abandonnément de raison.</dt>
      <dd>a wilfull defection, revolting, or swarming, from reason lorem ipsum dolor sit</dd>
    </dl>
  </dd>
</dl>
```

Comment: Is it possible to stop multiple sub-items inlining next to each other? (https://jsfiddle.net/vem5nLu3/)

Comment: Absolutely, you can wrap each set of dt and dd in it's own div https://jsfiddle.net/JHeth/q3we4aoj/1/ here's some info on it from MDN https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/dl#wrapping_name-value_groups_in_div_elements